# Do you know any PHP script or library to export/import dumps of MySQL databases?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, into-outfile

I don't have shell access so can't use the mysqldump command
Also the use of sentences like SELECT * INTO OUTFILE are restricted

SOLVED: I've found several PHP scripts/libraries/classes in google code.

Comment: I would almost guarantee that a PHP lib is going be a wrapper for `mysqldump`

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Do you want to write such a library and you need some help with it? Or do you want an already existing one for your project? What are all the tasks this library has to be able to do? Should it export all at once or only one DB at a time, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Than a `SELECT * FROM` and afterwards a `file_put_contents()`

Otherwise explain why not doing one of the following!

What do you want the output to look like? If it should look like a regular dump file, that good luck in writing your own PHP to mysql dump file converter.

Comment: Only reason I can guess is lack of shell access